# Why does my speed guage seem to have empty space above and below it?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am making a racing app for a go-kart and trying to add a speed guage widget. When I try to add it in with my other widgets, there seems to be empty space above and below the speed guage. In the photo I attached, there is supposed to be a battery life indicator widget directly underneath the speed guage, but it "overflows" even though there should be plenty of space.

This is the code for my speed guage widget:

```
 final double speed;

 SpeedGraph({required this.speed});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SfRadialGauge(axes: <RadialAxis>[
     RadialAxis(
       radiusFactor: .4,
       minimum: 0,
       maximum: 35,
       axisLineStyle: AxisLineStyle(thicknessUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor, thickness: 0.03),
       majorTickStyle: MajorTickStyle(length: 3, thickness: 3, color: Colors.white),
       minorTickStyle: MinorTickStyle(length: 3, thickness: 3, color: Colors.white),
       axisLabelStyle: GaugeTextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),
       ranges: <GaugeRange>[
         GaugeRange(
             startValue: 0,
             endValue: 35,
             sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
             startWidth: 0.03,
             endWidth: 0.03,
             gradient: SweepGradient(
                 colors: const <Color>[Colors.green, Colors.yellow, Colors.red], stops: const <double>[0.0, 0.5, 1]))
       ],
       pointers: <GaugePointer>[
         NeedlePointer(
             value: speed,
             needleLength: 0.7,
             enableAnimation: true,
             animationType: AnimationType.ease,
             needleStartWidth: 1.0,
             needleEndWidth: 3,
             needleColor: Colors.red,
             knobStyle: KnobStyle(knobRadius: 0.09, sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor))
       ],
       // annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
       //   GaugeAnnotation(
       //       widget: Container(
       //           child: Column(children: <Widget>[
       //         Text(speed.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
       //         SizedBox(height: 10),
       //         Text('mph', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
       //       ])),
       //       angle: 90,
       //       positionFactor: 0.75)
       // ]
     )
   ]);
 }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

[Display Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErkVF.jpg)

Comment: To me it seems like you made an error in layouting the elements(rather than in SpeedGraph itself).
Seems like text on the left and Speed Graph are in one Row() inside a Column() while Battery is in the that same Column() but not a Row().
Better provide the structure since that is your error and not the widget